# d3.js graph data attributes case senstive

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

i am using a d3.js graph and the data it is dependent on looks like:

```
 var graph = {
                                      "nodes" : [{"name" : "Appointments"},{"name" : "Store Visit"},{"name" : "Visit History"},{"name" : "Resume Store Visit"}], 
                                      "links" : [{"source":"Store Visit","target":"Appointments","value":6},
                                                {"source":"Appointments","target":"Visit History","value":7},
                                                {"source":"Visit History","target":"Store Visit","value":2},
                                                {"source":"Resume Store Visit","target":"Visit History","value":1},
                                                {"source":"Appointments","target":"Resume Store Visit","value":5}]
                                                };
```

my REST service returns the exact same data but the attribute names are Source, Target and Value (notice the first letter capital)

This breaks it with error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefinedl.start @ d3.v3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ userflowd3.html:64(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1t @ d3.v3.min.js:1u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
```

So, what would be the way for the json returning data.items to replace the attribute values to lower case?

Answer (score 0):

so i had to do 
like

```
  var gLinks = JSON.stringify(data.items);
                                      gLinks = gLinks.replace(/Source/g,'source');
                                      gLinks = gLinks.replace(/Target/g,'target');
                                      gLinks = gLinks.replace(/Value/g,'value');
                                      var arr = JSON.parse(gLinks);
```